# DoppioOne-Regular.ttf Font does no support ft character in android

Tags: android, fonts, typeface

I'm working on project in which I using DoppioOne-Regular.ttf font for typeface, but the problem is that when String contains 'ft' character then it look like pencil symbol.
  In following image I have a string "Ha´en fed aften!" but ft in the string look like pencil. Give me the soluion to recover from this isssue.[image]

Answer (score 3):

Can you please try this file: https://github.com/w0ng/googlefontdirectory/blob/master/fonts/DoppioOne-Regular.ttf?raw=true

When I tried it i got:

[image: Using the font provided]

And please can you attach the font you are using so that I can check it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you heard of the open-source program called [Font Forge](http://fontforge.org/)?  It allows you to open fonts, modify the vectors, and convert fonts.

## Install Font Forge on Ubuntu Linux from terminal

`sudo apt-get install -y fontforge`


I am unable to reproduce your problem, but that Font Forge could probably fix it.  I don't have that font.  Where did you retrieve this font file from?