# Google font displaying an icon instead of letter

Tags: webfonts

We are working on a project and one of the participants has a problem with a Google font (Doppio One). The problem occurs in Firefox 33.1 with windows 8.1

On certain places he sees an icon instead of the letters (ft). I can't find the solution. I can only find topics where letters a being displayed instead of icons. But my problem is the other way around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In another topic the same question is asked. Didn't notice it before:

[DoppioOne-Regular.ttf Font does no support ft character in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18998437/doppioone-regular-ttf-font-does-no-support-ft-character-in-android)

What i did:

Instead of inserting the font as a Google Font I downloaded the .ttf file and converted it into a webfont with Font Squirrel Webfont Generator.